# How to add count for each unique val in list

Tags: python, string, list, counter, defaultdict

Assume I have a list.

```
temp = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B']
```

I am looking for a way to join the count of the string inside.

Intended Output:

```
['A_1', 'B_1', 'A_2', 'B_2', 'A_3', 'B_3']
```

I was able to solve it by using a list comprehension but I am looking for a way where I don't have to specify the list `[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]`. Is it possible?

```
[j + "_" + str(i) for i, j in zip([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], temp)]
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) with a `for` loop:

```
from collections import defaultdict

L = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B']

dd = defaultdict(int)

res = []
for item in L:
    dd[item] += 1
    res.append(f'{item}_{dd[item]}')

print(res)

['A_1', 'B_1', 'A_2', 'B_2', 'A_3', 'B_3']
```

Comment: Thank you :). Is it possible to write this in a list comprehension?

Comment: @Rakesh yes, but only using very ugly side effects.

Comment: @timgeb Why would there be side effects? can you explain? I prefer a list comprehension rather than writing a for loop.

Comment: You would have to use boolean expressions inside the comprehension where the evaluation of the truthyness of its parts also calls methods like `__setitem__`. Trust me, you don't want a listcomp here.

Comment: Agree with @timgeb here, a list comprehension would work if you pre-calculated the index values (which would be overly expensive). But not when you need to calculate them based on *prior* values.

Comment: @timgeb: in fact you can do it with just a list comprehension, without using side effects *quite* as nasty as the ones you mention - see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53102542/333698) for one way of doing so. I'm still not 100% sure I'd recommend doing it, though :)

Answer (score 11):

You can use a `Counter` or a `defaultdict(int)` to keep track of how many times a character has been seen as you encounter them.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> 
>>> temp = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B']
>>> seen = Counter()
>>> 
>>> result = []
>>> for c in temp:
...:    seen.update(c)
...:    result.append('{}_{}'.format(c, seen[c]))
...:    
>>> result
>>> ['A_1', 'B_1', 'A_2', 'B_2', 'A_3', 'B_3']
```

Note that `seen.update(c)` might have unexpected results if you expect strings with more than one character in `temp`. Demo:

```
>>> seen = Counter()
>>> seen.update('ABC')
>>> seen
>>> Counter({'A': 1, 'B': 1, 'C': 1})
```

Depending on how you want to count and what kind of data you expect, you might want to use the line

```
seen[c] += 1
```

instead of

```
seen.update(c)
```

Alternatively, without any imports:

```
>>> seen = {}
>>> result = []
>>> 
>>> for c in temp:
...:    seen[c] = seen.get(c, 0) + 1
...:    result.append('{}_{}'.format(c, seen[c]))
...:    
>>> result
>>> ['A_1', 'B_1', 'A_2', 'B_2', 'A_3', 'B_3']
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a dictionary (or better yet, a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)) to maintain the counts for each item:

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B']
lst2 = []
d = defaultdict(int)

for item in lst:
    d[item] += 1
    lst2.append('{}_{}'.format(item, d[item]))

print(lst2)  # ['A_1', 'B_1', 'A_2', 'B_2', 'A_3', 'B_3']
```

To use a list comprehension here you'd need some way to update state (i.e. the counters) for each item as you iterate the original list. For that you could use a function with a default argument, e.g.:

```
def get_count(item, d=defaultdict(int)):
    d[item] += 1
    return '{}_{}'.format(item, d[item])

lst2 = [get_count(item) for item in lst]
print(lst2)  # ['A_1', 'B_1', 'A_2', 'B_2', 'A_3', 'B_3']
```

Answer (score 4):

It is in fact possible (as OP has asked in some of the comments) to do this with just a list comprehension, without too many undesirable side effects. I'm not sure whether this is necessarily a good idea though - some people may not find it the easiest code to understand:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import itertools

temp = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B']

result = [j + "_" + str(next(c[j]))
          for c in [defaultdict(itertools.count)]
          for j in temp]
```

Comment: nice, but I agree, the loop is more readable here. and may be more performant too.

Comment: @Baldrickk: Yep, I'm not advocating using this, at least without serious consideration first! And if high performance is a requirement, always measure :)

Comment: For Python 3 you should replace the `next()` method call with the `next()` function. And that also works with Python 2 then, so it's the better, because more portable solution.